# How (and which) can be the best java script and jQuery Intellisense for Visual Studio 2010 be incorportated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, intellisense

i am developing a web app which uses jQuery and Javascript extensively in Visual Studio 2010. currently the issue is whenever i write the code in jQuery / java script am not provided with any great intellisense.... am always pondering over internet for this, can anyone tell how to solve this ?

Comment: I'd recommend you ditch Visual Studio and use JetBrains WebStorm for your JavaScript development.  Using two IDEs side by side is far easier (IMO) than trying to use VS for JS

Comment: Another social networking app huh? Sounds exciting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use JSEnhancements:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0696ad60-1c68-4b2a-9646-4b5f4f8f2e06

It's not perfect, but it's a lot better than nothing, and the price is good (free).